# How to make Firebase Push Notification Increase Badge Count When Receive Notification In Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, badge

- First of all, this is a **self-answering question.**
- Second, I will try to describe in great detail the solution I have implemented for this situation.
- The problem posed: the badge attribute cannot be dynamically incremented
- source:
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.NotificationMessagePayload#badge.
- So how do I get this badge property to automatically increment.?
  The solution I have answered is below, **the 1st answer**
  Also when you do this on multiple mobile devices what you need is:

**IMPORTANT !!!**

- > DO THIS WHEN YOU HAVE FOLLOWED THE STEPS IN THE ANSWER BELOW !!!

B1. Included badge number in each token of devices.
[image]

B2. change this when app init and generate fcm-token

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('fcm-token').doc(device_name).set({'device1_pt1': token_id,'number': 0});
```

B3. Put this then onmessage is call.(by onlauch, onresume, onmessage)

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('fcm-token').doc(device_name).update({'number': 0});
```

Comment: if you want using this for multiple device you must include number badge in fcm-token_device. Use it on each of devices

Comment: Hey Jayce. Thank you for sharing your solution to this common problem. 
Can you put it in a Q&A format though? So: write a simple question, and then post what you now have as the answer. That way both the system and most users of Stack Overflow won't be confused, and your help will reach most people.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Okay

Answer (score 4):

B1. Create new Colection like [image: new Colection]
B2. In API(Handle Data):

> Data received: Data = {'token-device': String, 'body':'string'}

#Read badge number from firebase(create at B1):

```
badge = db.collection('badge').document('count').get()._data 
badge = badge['number'] badge += 1 #increate when receive new data. 
badgedx = db.collection('badge').document('count').update({'number' : badge})
Data['badge'] = str(badge) # must be string
```

> Data before save to firestore: Data = {'token-device': String, 'body':'string','badge':'1'}

```
#Save to firestore
addx = todo_ref.document() 
addx.set(Data) #save to firestore
```

B3.In Firebase-Function(file index.js)

```
> Add badge number 

 var badgecount = newData['badge'];
    var options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
      };
    var payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'title',
            body: 'Phiếu khảo sát khách hàng',
            sound: 'default',
            alert: 'alert',
            badge: badgecount,
        },
        data: {
            click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            key1: newData['content'],
        },
    };`
```

B4: In FLutter:
Reset badge number = 0

```
    _configureFirebaseListeners() {
      _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
      const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true),
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onMessage: $message');
         _setMessage(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onLaunch: $message');
         _setMessage(message);

      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onResume: $message');
         _setMessage(message);
      },
    );
 

 }
    _setMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message)  {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('badge').doc('count').set({'number': 0});
```

Demo:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UIP9BPiy-gQnk6I6rEzeporZaOwkPKTk/view?usp=sharing